# Generated Swagger REST client does not handle + character correctly for query parameter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, resttemplate, spring-web, swagger-codegen

I have this Spring REST controller method:

```
@ApiOperation("My method")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/myMethod")
public void myMethod(@RequestParam("myParam") String myParam) {
...
}
```

The REST client is generated using swagger codegen CLI with language *Java* and library *resttemplate*:

```
public void myMethod(String myParam) throws RestClientException {
    ...
    return apiClient.invokeAPI(path, HttpMethod.POST, queryParams, postBody, headerParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames, returnType);
}
```

And the source code for `ApiClient#invokeAPI` - which is also generated - is:

```
public <T> T invokeAPI(String path, HttpMethod method, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Object body, HttpHeaders headerParams, MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams, List<MediaType> accept, MediaType contentType, String[] authNames, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> returnType) throws RestClientException {
    updateParamsForAuth(authNames, queryParams, headerParams);

    final UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(basePath).path(path);
    if (queryParams != null) {
        builder.queryParams(queryParams);
    }

    final BodyBuilder requestBuilder = RequestEntity.method(method, builder.build().toUri());
    if(accept != null) {
        requestBuilder.accept(accept.toArray(new MediaType[accept.size()]));
    }
    if(contentType != null) {
        requestBuilder.contentType(contentType);
    }

    addHeadersToRequest(headerParams, requestBuilder);
    addHeadersToRequest(defaultHeaders, requestBuilder);

    RequestEntity<Object> requestEntity = requestBuilder.body(selectBody(body, formParams, contentType));

    ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, returnType);
    ...
}
```

Now, when I call `myMethod` passing a string containing a `+` sign in `myParam`, at the server I receive a space character instead of the `+`. Seems to be an encoding issue since the plus sign is reserved in URL query parameters to be a replacement for the space character. Is this a bug from swagger codegen or from Spring classes or no bug at all? How can I fix that?

**EDIT:**

Swagger definition is like (generated from Spring REST controller):

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  ...
  "paths": {
    "/myMethod": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "myMethod",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "myParam",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
           ...
        }
      }
    }
 ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Similar problems seems to be the encoding of path variables. When I pass `"bla:bla/bla"` to a path variable the special characters `:` and `/` will not be encoded but send as is which causes an error server side because the mapping not found.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I initiate it via the `myMethod` method in the generated client class. It will use a Spring RestTemplate finally as you can see in the `invokeApi` method code which is generated, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165870/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-steffen-harbich).

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Not for now. Your solution will work but I still think it is a workaround. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7747) at Github swagger codegen project.

Answer (score 0):

A `+` usually means a space in url params. This is a standard. Your url gets generated on below line of code

```
final BodyBuilder requestBuilder = RequestEntity.method(method, builder.build().toUri());
```

And `+` is not encoded as it is a valid value to have which will be then later converted to space at the receiving end. Now when you try use `%2B` the above line of code sees that you have a un-encoded `%` character and it converts it to `%252B`.

When you receive this back at Spring it converts it back to `%2B` for you. One way to solve the issue is to send encoded values yourself. So you will change

```
 final BodyBuilder requestBuilder = RequestEntity.method(method, builder.build().toUri());
```

to

```
final BodyBuilder requestBuilder = RequestEntity.method(method, builder.build(true).toUri());
```

And then call the API method as

```
client.myMethod("tarun%2blalwani")
```

And now spring will receive `tarun+lalwani` as shown below

[image: + in spring]

Comment: it is NOT standard for a `+` to mean a space in query string params.. in datetime strings, e.g. `2018-01-01T12:00:00+04:00` the `+` is significant and certainly does not mean a space.