# What's the proper way to escape URL variables with Spring's RestTemplate when calling a Spring RestController?

Tags: spring, resttemplate

When calling `RestTemplate.exchange` to do a get request, such as:

```
String foo = "fo+o";
String bar = "ba r";
restTemplate.exchange("http://example.com/?foo={foo}&bar={bar}", HttpMethod.GET, null, foo, bar)
```

what's the proper to have the URL variables correctly escaped for the get request?

Specifically, how do I get pluses (`+`) correctly escaped because [Spring is interpreting as spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270372/why-is-spring-de-coding-the-plus-character-on-application-json-get-requests), so, I need to encode them.

I tried using `UriComponentsBuilder` like this:

```
String foo = "fo+o";
String bar = "ba r";
UriComponentsBuilder ucb = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://example.com/?foo={foo}&bar={bar}");
System.out.println(ucb.build().expand(foo, bar).toUri());
System.out.println(ucb.build().expand(foo, bar).toString());
System.out.println(ucb.build().expand(foo, bar).toUriString());
System.out.println(ucb.build().expand(foo, bar).encode().toUri());
System.out.println(ucb.build().expand(foo, bar).encode().toString());
System.out.println(ucb.build().expand(foo, bar).encode().toUriString());
System.out.println(ucb.buildAndExpand(foo, bar).toUri());
System.out.println(ucb.buildAndExpand(foo, bar).toString());
System.out.println(ucb.buildAndExpand(foo, bar).toUriString());
System.out.println(ucb.buildAndExpand(foo, bar).encode().toUri());
System.out.println(ucb.buildAndExpand(foo, bar).encode().toString());
System.out.println(ucb.buildAndExpand(foo, bar).encode().toUriString());
```

and that printed:

```
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
```

The space is correctly escaped in some instances, but the plus is never escaped.

I also tried `UriTemplate` like this:

```
String foo = "fo+o";
String bar = "ba r";
UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate("http://example.com/?foo={foo}&bar={bar}");
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<>();
vars.put("foo", foo);
vars.put("bar", bar);
URI uri = uriTemplate.expand(vars);
System.out.println(uri);
```

with the exact same result:

```
http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r
```

Comment: Use UriTemplate and call expand on it. It will return a string with the url correctly escaped.

Comment: @ShayElkayam: are you sure about that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apparently, the correct way of doing this is by defining a factory and changing the encoding mode:

```
String foo = "fo+o";
String bar = "ba r";
DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
URI uri = factory.uriString("http://example.com/?foo={foo}&bar={bar}").build(foo, bar);
System.out.println(uri);
```

That prints out:

```
http://example.com/?foo=fo%2Bo&bar=ba%20r
```

This is documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#web-uri-encoding

Comment: I think this solution can be applied for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906034).

Answer (score 10):

I think your problem here is that [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), on which `UriComponents` and by extension `UriTemplate` are based, *does not* mandate the escaping of `+` in a query string.

The spec's view on this is simply:

```
sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                  / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

pchar       = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"

query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )

URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

If your web framework (Spring MVC, for example!) is interpreting `+` as a space, then that is its decision and not required under the URI spec.

With reference to the above, you will also see that `!$'()*+,;` are not escaped by `UriTemplate`. `=` and `&` *are* escaped because Spring has taken an "opinionated" view of what a query string looks like -- a sequence of key=value pairs.

Likewise, `#[]` and whitespace *are* escaped because they are illegal in a query string under the spec.

Granted, none of this is likely to be any consolation to you if you just quite reasonably want your query parameters escaped!

To actually encode the query params so your web framework can tolerate them, you could use something like `org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.encode(foo, charset)`.

Comment: The problem is that Spring is being inconsistent here. And if I pre-encode + as %2B by calling UriUtils.encode, then, the % gets further encoded by UriTemplate breaking the string.

Comment: I don't think it's inconsistent. If you've already encoded your params, Spring can't know that. You can tell it you've already encoded them with e.g. `UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://example.com/?foo={foo}").queryParams(...).build(true).toUriString()`

Answer (score 7):

I'm starting to believe this is a bug and I reported here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16860

Currently, my workaround is this:

```
String foo = "fo+o";
String bar = "ba r";
String uri = UriComponentsBuilder.
    fromUriString("http://example.com/?foo={foo}&bar={bar}").
    buildAndExpand(vars).toUriString();
uri = uri.replace("+", "%2B"); // This is the horrible hack.
try {
    return new URI(uriString);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("UriComponentsBuilder generated an invalid URI.", e);
}
```

which is a horrible hack that might fail in some situations.

Comment: See the answer I posted, this uses everything from URIBuilder and adds a workaround to encode and send the query components.

Answer (score 6):

For this one I would still prefer the encoding to be resolved using a proper method instead of using a Hack like you did. I would just use something like below

```
String foo = "fo+o";
String bar = "ba r";
MyUriComponentsBuilder ucb = MyUriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://example.com/?foo={foo}&bar={bar}");

UriComponents uriString = ucb.buildAndExpand(foo, bar);
// http://example.com/?foo=fo%252Bo&bar=ba+r
URI x = uriString.toUri();

// http://example.com/?foo=fo%2Bo&bar=ba+r
String y = uriString.toUriString();

// http://example.com/?foo=fo%2Bo&bar=ba+r
String z = uriString.toString();
```

And of course the class is like below

```
class MyUriComponentsBuilder extends UriComponentsBuilder {
    protected UriComponentsBuilder originalBuilder; 

    public MyUriComponentsBuilder(UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        originalBuilder = builder;
    }


    public static MyUriComponentsBuilder fromUriString(String uri) {
        return new MyUriComponentsBuilder(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri));
    }


    @Override
    public UriComponents buildAndExpand(Object... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i< values.length; i ++) {
            try {
                values[i] = URLEncoder.encode((String) values[i], StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return originalBuilder.buildAndExpand(values);
    }

}
```

Still not a cleanest possible way but better then doing a hardcoded replace approach

Answer (score 2):

You could use [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) in Spring (org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromUriString("http://example.com/")
    .queryParam("foo", "fo+o")
    .queryParam("bar", "ba r")
    .build().toUriString();

restTemplate.exchange(url , HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity);
```

Comment: Do you mean `foo` instead of `"{foo}"`?

Comment: You can just use the variables `foo` and `bar` like I did in my question. Another difference is that I'm using a template in my question. Not sure if this is relevant, but using a template with `UriCompontentsBuilder`, it seems not to escape the `+`.

Comment: See updated answer. UriComponentsBuilder will appropriately escape

Comment: Does not work for me. If I output with `System.out.println(url);`, I get

`http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba r`

Comment: Adding `.encode()` after (or before) `.build()` will give me `http://example.com/?foo=fo+o&bar=ba%20r`