# Spring rest controller removes plus sign from zonedatetime in query parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, zoneddatetime

I have UT, that succesfully passed

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String text1 = "2009-07-10T14:30:01.001Z";
        String text2 = "2009-07-10T14:30:01.001+03:00";
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(text1, f);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(text2, f);

        System.out.println(zonedDateTime1);
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime2);
    }
```

The output is

```
2009-07-10T14:30:01.001Z
2009-07-10T14:30:01.001+03:00
```

But, when I try to use this pattern on spring-controller

```
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity get( @RequestParam("start") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ")
                                               ZonedDateTime start) {
        Dto result = service.get(start);
        return new ResponseEntity(result, getHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

It works only when I pass Z instead timezone, for example

```
2009-07-10T14:30:01.001Z
```

But when try to pass timezone offset - there is error message

> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.time.ZonedDateTime'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
>   java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value '2009-07-10T14:30:01.001 03:00';
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt
>   failed for value [2009-07-10T14:30:01.001 03:00]",

I try to pass request by postman like this

```
POST localhost:9080/MyApp/user?start=2009-07-10T14:30:01.001+03:00
header: Content-Type application/json
```

Comment: check your input, in error message it clearly says `+` is missing `2009-07-10T14:30:01.001 03:00`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to encode the [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432395/whats-the-proper-way-to-escape-url-variables-with-springs-resttemplate-when-ca) when you have special characters like [plus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270372/why-is-spring-de-coding-the-plus-character-on-application-json-get-requests) (`+`)

```
POST localhost:9080/MyApp/user?start=2009-07-10T14:30:01.001%2B03:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode request variables like explained in [docu](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web-uri-encoding).

for tests You may use following example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15132#issuecomment-437431903